# git: updating vender branch

Tags: git

I have a git repository with `master` and `dev` branches. There is also a vender branch `vender` that I use to update my third party libraries.

Now I've been into the project for some time and have committed a good amount of changes and have also updated the third party code a few times. (I never add my own changes to third party libs, just update them from the source)

What I *used to* do is: (perhaps wrongly)

```
(dev) $ git checkout vender
(vender) $ git merge dev
(vender) $ ... update third party libraries ...
(vender) $ git commit -am '...'
(vender) $ git checkout dev
(dev) $ git merge vender
```

This way I first merge entire `dev` into `vender` and then after updating `vender`, I merge it back into `dev`. What this did is it brought all the history into the `vender` branch that is NOT related to updating the third party libraries. **I wanted to have the log in my `vender` branch to include ONLY the commits about updating the third party libs.**

I think I was wrong in merging `dev` into `vender` (I assumed all the code has to be in every branch -- as I am a git noob).

My first question is:

is it ok to NOT merge `dev` into `vender` and keep updating it (I guess doing so will show the `vender` log containing only the third party update commits)

NOW, at this point, I have a very dirty `vender` branch -- it contains ALL the commits that I made in `dev`, which have nothing to do with third party code. What should I do now to get `vender` branch to be correctly showing only the third party update related commits?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you shouldn't merge `dev` into `vender` since that is not needed.

1. `git stash` any unsaved changes you may have, just in case.
2. `git reflog` to see a log of all of the changes you have made, including changing branches and such. This log shows all of the things you have done, going backward in time, and is the main tool for fixing this.
3. Find the point in the log where you ran `git merge dev`, then get the SHA from the line below that one (earlier), which will probably say `checkout: moving from dev to vendor`.
4. With `vendor` checked out, run `git reset --hard <SHA>` which will put `vendor` back where it was before all of this happened.
5. Find the log line/SHA for each commit that you did for updating third party libraries, and run `git cherry-pick <SHA>` to re-apply that commit on top of `vender`.
6. At this point `vender` is all fixed, but we still need to go back and fix `dev`.
7. `git checkout dev`
8. Find the point in the log where you had dev checked out, which will probably be the one before the SHA you found in step 3.
9. Run `git reset --hard <SHA>` on that to put dev back where it was originally before all of this.
10. `git merge vender` to merge `vender` into `dev` correctly.

At this point, it might also be a good idea to use GitX or gitk to make sure your history looks reasonable. And please make backups before doing this just in case :)

Alternatively for steps `3.` and `9.`, you may be able to run `git reset --hard origin/vender` and `git reset --hard origin/dev` if you have not pushed any of these changes back to the server yet, assuming you have a server.

Comment: Thanks -- I don't completely understand what you describe but will try to do it step by step. One thing I don't understand is why do we need to reset the `dev` branch? Also, since I merged `dev` into `vender` multiple times, I need to follow these steps those many times -- right ?

Comment: You need to reset dev because you merged vendor into dev, and at that point vendor was based on dev. Basically to undo and redo your last ` git merge vender` line. What do you mean you merged `dev` into `vender` multiple times? You only showed it ones in your line of commands. Also please be aware that you are changing history here, so if you pushed any of this to a server and other people are working on it, should should NOT do any of this.

Comment: No, I haven't pushed on the server so I can change the history. By multiple times I mean I merged `dev` into `vender` every time I wanted to update the third party code in `vender`. That is, I would first merge `dev` into `vender`, and then update the third party code.

Comment: @good_computer So, you did the set of commands `git merge dev`, made a library change, then did `git commit -am "stuff"` multiple times before going back to dev and merging in `vender`? That's probably fine as long as you reset to before all of that. Have you made any other changes since then? Like real commits on dev, or anything else? I was assuming your list of commands was exactly what you had run, if there is other stuff you didn't mention, things are possibly a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You did a merge and not a rebase, correct?  To clean up the vender branch, you should be able to do a `git reset <commit>`.  If it's interspersed (which it kind of sounds like it is), then that'll be a headache.

Do you have some way of distinguishing the vender branch commits from the dev commits?  If so, you could try an interactive rebase to drop the bad commits.  Something like `git rebase -i <commit>` would get you started.